# Sonata Admin Enable action

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony for make a web site and I installed sonata admin Bundle.
I have an entity with a boolean variable (enable).
I would like when this variable change state to True the other one for the same table go to False. In fact I would like only one variable (enable) for the same table is at True.

So I thought to change setEnable directly in my Entity but I can't get the repository from my Entity class.

*How can I get my repository from my Entity Class ?*

Answer (score 1):

You should use lifecycleCallbacks to do this (with preUpdate), check doc for a good configuration.
And do something like this :

```
   public function preUpload()
       {
           if ($this->getVariable1())
               $this->setVariable2(false);
       }
```

Comment: Ok thank you I put it in my Entity class with @ORM\PreUpdate() annotation. My second problem now is how can I access to my other objects of this Entity for update them? Cause I can't use getEntityManager() in Entity Class.

Comment: You don't need to use the EntityManager, i edited my first post, check it.

Comment: But I'd like change the other objects of the table. For exemple $object1->setVariable(false); $object2->setVariable(false); $this->setVariable(true);

Answer (score 0):

I think you might change prospective. 
If this behavior is a logic of your application it's better to do a doctrine subscriber. So when you persist or update your entity it's will be checked.

Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

In your specific case this will be done with this simple code:

```
 use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;


class ObjectSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{



public function __construct($objectManager)
{
}


public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'postPersist',
        'postUpdate',
    );
}


public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->manage($args);
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->manage($args);
}

public function manage(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof YourEntity) {
        if ($entity->getEnable()) {
            $em = $args->getEntityManager();
            $entities = $em->getRepository('YourEntityRepository')->findByEnable(true);
            foreach ($entities as $e) {
                if ($e->getId() == $entity->getId()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $e->setEnable(false);
            }
            $em->flush();

        }
    }
}


}
```